# RegEx Is Not Working As It Should

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following JS regex which breaks the code and not working as it should.

```
var loginFailedRegex = /https:\/\/encore.lsbu.ac.uk\/iii\/cas\/login;jsessionid=[a-z0-9]*?service=https%3A%2F%2Flispac.lsbu.ac.uk%3A443%2Fpatroninfo~S1%2FIIITICKET/i;

if (loginFailedRegex.text(decodeURI(loc))) {
   zoomPagePortion(100, 100);
}
```

The **loginFailedRegex** has only **[a-z0-9]*** as regex and other whole string is static.

Comment: A regexp does not have a `.text` function - what is it supposed to perform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the regex problem is here

```
[a-z0-9]*?
```

you should probably have

```
[a-z0-9]*\?
```

Assuming that `?` is a literal in the URL that you are looking for you need to escape it in your regex.

Also you need to change `text` to `test` assuming that is not just a typo in your post.

```
var loginFailedRegex = /https:\/\/encore.lsbu.ac.uk\/iii\/cas\/login;jsessionid=[a-z0-9]*\?service=https%3A%2F%2Flispac.lsbu.ac.uk%3A443%2Fpatroninfo~S1%2FIIITICKET/i;

if (loginFailedRegex.test(decodeURI(loc))) {
   zoomPagePortion(100, 100);
}
```

Here is a test page to verify

http://jsfiddle.net/cordsen/uVnZz/